# Control is not waiting till the thread finish its work

Tags: c#, multithreading

Below is my code , 
I know its not good coding practice , just creating a template to simulate `thread` processing with parameter and return value 
The problem it is reaching to last lines before invoked function finished , that causing `exception`

```
public class data_holder
{
    public DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
}
class Program
{
    public static List<int> int_list1 = new List<int>();
    public static List<int> int_list2 = new List<int>();
    public static bool done = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        data_holder dh = new data_holder();
        dh.dtable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
        dh.dtable.Columns.Add("DOB", typeof(DateTime));
        dh.dtable.Columns.Add("Refno", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dh.dtable.NewRow();
            dr["Id"] = i.ToString();
            dr["DOB"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
            dr["Refno"] = new Guid();
            dh.dtable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(processTable);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ts);
        t1.Start();
        t1.Join();
        if (done == true)
        //while(!done)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dh.dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(dh.dtable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                sb.Append("    ");
                sb.Append(dh.dtable.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                sb.Append("    ");
                sb.Append(dh.dtable.Rows[i][2].ToString());
                sb.Append("    ");
                sb.Append(dh.dtable.Rows[i][3].ToString());
                sb.Append("    ");
                sb.Append(dh.dtable.Rows[i][4].ToString());
                sb.Append("    ");
                sb.Append(dh.dtable.Rows[i][5].ToString());
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void processTable()
    {
        data_holder dh = new data_holder();
        dh.dtable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        dh.dtable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        dh.dtable.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 0; i < dh.dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dh.dtable.Rows[i]["col1"] = "col_1_Dummy";
            dh.dtable.Rows[i]["col2"] = "col_2_Dummy";
            dh.dtable.Rows[i]["col3"] = "col_3_Dummy";
        }
        done = true;                   
    }}
```

It is showing error at

```
sb.Append(dh.dtable.Rows[i][3].ToString());
```

> Error :{"Cannot find column 3."}

I know its because `datatable` is not yet ready , Should not execution control wait till call to `processTable()` finished ?

Comment: Instead of `Rows[i][3]` try it with `Rows[i][2]`

Comment: It will work with Rows[i][2] , but purpose is to process some record in it (adding resultant column with values in it) and than show complete table

Comment: Your `Main` and your `processTable` are using different instances of `data_holder`. In other words, they are both independently calling `new data_holder()`. I think you should create a static instance of `data_holder`.

Comment: Great , problem solved , Thanks @vyrp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution
credit @vyrp
There were two instance of data_holder and that was creating the problem
declared it as

```
   public static  data_holder dh = new data_holder();
```

and it works as expectation.

Answer (score 0):

`processTable` works with local `dh` variable and do nothing with global `dh` variable

So `Rows[i][3]` is referring to the forth column of `[i]`-s row, which doesn't exist.

That's what exception is saying about.

Comment: processTable is not generating any rows, it is adding three columns in previously added row and some values are getting added into it. It is running on thread , so my guess execution control is reaching to that line before values filled in it

Comment: Ok , thats a hint . But should not thread t1 run function processTable , which will add new column in same table ?

Comment: @Saurabh no `processTable` will work with a new variable. You can for example pass `data_holder` instance into `processTable` method, but make sure not to use it from several threads simultaneously anyway